# How to fix NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that filter data from api and set filtered data to new Map:

```
_addUpAndGetPercentage(List states) {

  Map<String, dynamic> _states = {
    "Stress": [],
    "Fatigue": [],
    "Anxiety": [],
    "Relaxation": [],
    "Involvement": []
  };

  log("states === $states");  // states === [{externalSessionId: 19dd1148-97e3-4e33-8cd6-9d4ab3b8d64c, iaf: 11, iapf: 9, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}}, {externalSessionId: d1d6637a-a445-467d-b658-91e42b080ed6, iaf: 12, iapf: 8, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}}]

  for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

    var shortcut = states[i]["states"];

    log("Stress ==== ${states[i]['states'].toString()}");

    if (states[i]["Stress"] != null) {
      _states[i]["Stress"].add(states[i]["Stress"]);
    } else {
      log("ERROOROROROOROR ==== ${states[i]['states'].toString()}");
      _states["Stress"].add(0);
    }

    if (shortcut["Anxiety"] != null) {
      _states["Anxiety"].add(shortcut["Anxiety"]);
    } else {
      _states["Anxiety"].add(0);
    }
  }

  log("_states ===== ${_states.toString()}");

  return _states;
}
```

And I am getting an error when I change **states[i]["Stress"]** to **shortcut["Stress"]** => **NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.**

But `log("Stress ==== ${states[i]['states'].toString()}");` returns me `Stress ==== {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}`

**shortcut["Anxiety"]** works properly and doesn't return me an error, only **shortcut["Stress"]** and I don't understand why..

If I remove **shortcut["Stress"]** and set **states[i]["Stress"]** then error doesn't come up but it doesn't work like I want to, this is my logs when I set **states[i]["Stress"]**:

```
states === [{externalSessionId: 19dd1148-97e3-4e33-8cd6-9d4ab3b8d64c, iaf: 11, iapf: 9, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}}, {externalSessionId: d1d6637a-a445-467d-b658-91e42b080ed6, iaf: 12, iapf: 8, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}}]
[log] Stress ==== {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}
[log] ERROOROROROOROR ==== {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}
[log] Stress ==== {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}
[log] ERROOROROROOROR ==== {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}

[log] _states ===== {Stress: [0, 0], Anxiety: [2, 5]}
states === [{externalSessionId: 19dd1148-97e3-4e33-8cd6-9d4ab3b8d64c, iaf: 11, iapf: 9, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}}, {externalSessionId: d1d6637a-a445-467d-b658-91e42b080ed6, iaf: 12, iapf: 8, startTime: null, endTime: null, states: {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}}]
[log] Stress ==== {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}
[log] ERROOROROROOROR ==== {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}
[log] Stress ==== {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}
[log] ERROOROROROOROR ==== {Stress: 1, Involvement: 1, Slight Fatigue: 2, Anxiety: 5, Relaxation: 2, Chronic Fatigue: 3}
[log] _states ===== {Stress: [0, 0], Anxiety: [2, 5]}
```

Stress should be [1,1]

If I add:

```
if (shortcut["Involvement"] != null) {
      _states["Involvement"].add(shortcut["Involvement"]);
    } else {
      _states["Involvement"].add(0);
    }
```

Then this involvement works properly, if add relaxation then relaxation returns me null error like stress..

Comment: Hey, big man what happened i thought got the answer correct last time

Comment: @Georgina, thanks for your answer, it really helped me a lot. But this time I want to find out why my code didn't work. This code here was written before your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe since Stress is part of `states: {Anxiety: 2, Stress: 1, Chronic Fatigue: 1}`

Instead of this:

```
 if (states[i]["Stress"] != null) {
      _states[i]["Stress"].add(states[i]["Stress"]);
    } else {
      log("ERROOROROROOROR ==== ${states[i]['states'].toString()}");
      _states["Stress"].add(0);
    }
```

you should have this:

```dart
 if (states[i]["states"]["Stress"] != null) {
      _states[i]["Stress"].add(states[i]["states"]["Stress"]);
    } else {
      log("ERROOROROROOROR ==== ${states[i]['states'].toString()}");
      _states["Stress"].add(0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me again!! I found the solution.. I just needed to remove [I] in _states[I]["Stresss"]. I feel like I am an idiot --_-